# Função que enumera letras do alfabeto

Tags: javascript, array, string, algoritmo

Como converter as letras do alfabeto em um *array de números* de acordo com sua sequência?

O *array* deve começar à partir do nº 1, não zero. Assim a letra `A` valeria `1`, `B` valeria `2`, `C` valeria `3`, e assim por diante.

Passarei como argumento as letras em sequência sem espaços ou qualquer tipo de delimitador.

As letras poderão ser passadas em qualquer conjunto, ex: "ac" (deve resultar em `[1, 3]`); ou "ca" (deve resultar em `[3, 1]`).

É possível trabalhar com outros tipos de alfabeto, como o russo: `А` valeria `1`; `Б` valeria `2`; `В` valeria `3`; `Г` valeria `4`, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa montar uma tabela com seu alfabeto. Pode colocar as letras que quiser de qualquer alfabeto, na ordem que quiser. Aí basta fazer o que se chama de *lookup* nesta tabela.

```
function converte(letras) {
    var alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var codigos = [];
    for (var i in letras) {
        codigos.push(alfabeto.indexOf(letras[i].toUpperCase()) + 1);
    }
    return codigos;
}

var resultado = converte("acdA");
for (var i in resultado) {
    console.log(resultado[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4QCMjQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lnkibcfg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Alphabet.js).

Nesta solução, você pode colocar o alfabeto à vontade, qualquer alfabeto, na ordem que quiser, pode até inventar algo. O importante é colocar o caractere desejado na posição do *array* que deseja o resultado (considerando que no *array* começa em zero, por isto o algoritmo faz o acerto para 1). Poderia-se também deixar o primeiro elemento do *array* como algo nulo e sem utilidade, aí o algoritmo não teria que somar um.

## Alternativa

Se tiver que considerar caracteres acentuados como sendo o mesmo caractere, tem que adicionar uma função para normalizar a *string*. Se alguém precisar:

```
function converte(letras) {
    let alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    let codigos = [];
    for (let i in letras) codigos.push(alfabeto.indexOf(removeAcento(letras[i].toUpperCase())) + 1);
    return codigos;
}

function removeAcento(letra) {
    let acentos = {
    "ÁÅÃÀÂÄ" : "A",
    "ÉÊÈË" : "E",
    "ÍÎÌÏ" : "I",
    "ÓÕÒÔÖ" : "O",
    "ÚÙÛÜ" : "U",
    "Ç" : "C"
    };
    for (let key in acentos) {
        for (let a = 0; a < key.length; a++) if (letra === key[a]) return acentos[key];
    }
    return letra;
}

let resultado = converte("acdAé");
for (let i in resultado) console.log(resultado[i]);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/15P8fu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tfjifqfb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Alphabet2.js).

Se for necessário usar outros alfabetos - não só cirílico ou grego, é só mudar as letras usadas.

Comment: Gostei da sua solução, porém no Console do firefox informa o seguinte erro `SyntaxError: missing ( after for`, notei que quando eu retiro o `each` da frente do `for` não dá mais erro, só que não funciona como esperado. Também não entendi a razão do segundo `for each`, fora da função. O resultado esperado tem de ser algo tipo: `console.log(converte('acbed'));` = `Array [ 1, 3, 2, 5, 4 ]`, mas parece que a do link do Site Ideone é um pouco diferente. Poderia realizar tais modificações, por gentileza?

Comment: @eden eu modifiquei. Me desculpe eu uso muitas linguagens, às vezes confundo elas. Funcionou em uma implementação do JS mas não funciona em todas. Agora usei uma forma que funciona em todas. Não fica tão elegante mas a prioridade é funcionar. O `print` é necessário no ideone porque ele não tem `comsole.log`, mas é só trocar um pelo outro. Usei o segundo `for` para mostrar o resultado, ou seja, imprimir item por item do *array*.Para obter o resultado não precisa fazer as 3 última linhas, mas sem elas não tem como imprimir o resultado.Se precisa formatar como quiser a impressão, aí só só adaptar

Comment: `@bigown` - Ficou perfeito! Funciona exatamente do jeito que eu esperava, você mencionou acima a "função para normalizar a string", ficaria muito grato se pudesse adicionar essa funcionalidade, daí eu encerro aceitando sua resposta como a mais útil. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: @eden você precisa que seja desconsiderado se está em maiúsculas e minúsculas e trate tudo como uma coisa spo? Por exemplo `A` e `a` valeriam 1? E mesmo se tiver acento, ou seja se encontrar `á` ou `ã` também valerá 1? Precisa deixar isto claro o critério (seria bom editar a pergunta para clarificar isto).

Comment: `@bigown` - Não deve haver diferença entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, ambas se equivaleriam (`A` e `a` valeriam 1), mas caracteres acentuados não devem ter o mesmo valor (`á` e `ã` NÃO valeriam 1).

Comment: @eden veja se está ok agora.

Comment: `@bigown` - Funcionou muito bem, muito obrigado por mais esta modificação.

Answer (score 7):

Uma outra alternativa que pode ser utilizada é:

```js
function enumerarLetras(texto){
    texto = texto.toLowerCase();
    var numeros = [];
    texto.split('').map(function(letra){
        numeros.push((letra.charCodeAt(0) - 97) + 1);
    });
    return numeros;
}

alert(enumerarLetras('ACBED'));
```

**Nota**: A função acima funciona somente em casos que o texto não tenha acentos, ela funciona somente com os caracteres do [alfabeto latino](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_latino).

O código abaixo foi baseado na [resposta do TobyMosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54423/6454) e [nessa do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9667752/1608936).

```js
var Latinise={};Latinise.latin_map={"Á":"A","Ă":"A","Ắ":"A","Ặ":"A","Ằ":"A","Ẳ":"A","Ẵ":"A","Ǎ":"A","Â":"A","Ấ":"A","Ậ":"A","Ầ":"A","Ẩ":"A","Ẫ":"A","Ä":"A","Ǟ":"A","Ȧ":"A","Ǡ":"A","Ạ":"A","Ȁ":"A","À":"A","Ả":"A","Ȃ":"A","Ā":"A","Ą":"A","Å":"A","Ǻ":"A","Ḁ":"A","Ⱥ":"A","Ã":"A","Ꜳ":"AA","Æ":"AE","Ǽ":"AE","Ǣ":"AE","Ꜵ":"AO","Ꜷ":"AU","Ꜹ":"AV","Ꜻ":"AV","Ꜽ":"AY","Ḃ":"B","Ḅ":"B","Ɓ":"B","Ḇ":"B","Ƀ":"B","Ƃ":"B","Ć":"C","Č":"C","Ç":"C","Ḉ":"C","Ĉ":"C","Ċ":"C","Ƈ":"C","Ȼ":"C","Ď":"D","Ḑ":"D","Ḓ":"D","Ḋ":"D","Ḍ":"D","Ɗ":"D","Ḏ":"D","ǲ":"D","ǅ":"D","Đ":"D","Ƌ":"D","Ǳ":"DZ","Ǆ":"DZ","É":"E","Ĕ":"E","Ě":"E","Ȩ":"E","Ḝ":"E","Ê":"E","Ế":"E","Ệ":"E","Ề":"E","Ể":"E","Ễ":"E","Ḙ":"E","Ë":"E","Ė":"E","Ẹ":"E","Ȅ":"E","È":"E","Ẻ":"E","Ȇ":"E","Ē":"E","Ḗ":"E","Ḕ":"E","Ę":"E","Ɇ":"E","Ẽ":"E","Ḛ":"E","Ꝫ":"ET","Ḟ":"F","Ƒ":"F","Ǵ":"G","Ğ":"G","Ǧ":"G","Ģ":"G","Ĝ":"G","Ġ":"G","Ɠ":"G","Ḡ":"G","Ǥ":"G","Ḫ":"H","Ȟ":"H","Ḩ":"H","Ĥ":"H","Ⱨ":"H","Ḧ":"H","Ḣ":"H","Ḥ":"H","Ħ":"H","Í":"I","Ĭ":"I","Ǐ":"I","Î":"I","Ï":"I","Ḯ":"I","İ":"I","Ị":"I","Ȉ":"I","Ì":"I","Ỉ":"I","Ȋ":"I","Ī":"I","Į":"I","Ɨ":"I","Ĩ":"I","Ḭ":"I","Ꝺ":"D","Ꝼ":"F","Ᵹ":"G","Ꞃ":"R","Ꞅ":"S","Ꞇ":"T","Ꝭ":"IS","Ĵ":"J","Ɉ":"J","Ḱ":"K","Ǩ":"K","Ķ":"K","Ⱪ":"K","Ꝃ":"K","Ḳ":"K","Ƙ":"K","Ḵ":"K","Ꝁ":"K","Ꝅ":"K","Ĺ":"L","Ƚ":"L","Ľ":"L","Ļ":"L","Ḽ":"L","Ḷ":"L","Ḹ":"L","Ⱡ":"L","Ꝉ":"L","Ḻ":"L","Ŀ":"L","Ɫ":"L","ǈ":"L","Ł":"L","Ǉ":"LJ","Ḿ":"M","Ṁ":"M","Ṃ":"M","Ɱ":"M","Ń":"N","Ň":"N","Ņ":"N","Ṋ":"N","Ṅ":"N","Ṇ":"N","Ǹ":"N","Ɲ":"N","Ṉ":"N","Ƞ":"N","ǋ":"N","Ñ":"N","Ǌ":"NJ","Ó":"O","Ŏ":"O","Ǒ":"O","Ô":"O","Ố":"O","Ộ":"O","Ồ":"O","Ổ":"O","Ỗ":"O","Ö":"O","Ȫ":"O","Ȯ":"O","Ȱ":"O","Ọ":"O","Ő":"O","Ȍ":"O","Ò":"O","Ỏ":"O","Ơ":"O","Ớ":"O","Ợ":"O","Ờ":"O","Ở":"O","Ỡ":"O","Ȏ":"O","Ꝋ":"O","Ꝍ":"O","Ō":"O","Ṓ":"O","Ṑ":"O","Ɵ":"O","Ǫ":"O","Ǭ":"O","Ø":"O","Ǿ":"O","Õ":"O","Ṍ":"O","Ṏ":"O","Ȭ":"O","Ƣ":"OI","Ꝏ":"OO","Ɛ":"E","Ɔ":"O","Ȣ":"OU","Ṕ":"P","Ṗ":"P","Ꝓ":"P","Ƥ":"P","Ꝕ":"P","Ᵽ":"P","Ꝑ":"P","Ꝙ":"Q","Ꝗ":"Q","Ŕ":"R","Ř":"R","Ŗ":"R","Ṙ":"R","Ṛ":"R","Ṝ":"R","Ȑ":"R","Ȓ":"R","Ṟ":"R","Ɍ":"R","Ɽ":"R","Ꜿ":"C","Ǝ":"E","Ś":"S","Ṥ":"S","Š":"S","Ṧ":"S","Ş":"S","Ŝ":"S","Ș":"S","Ṡ":"S","Ṣ":"S","Ṩ":"S","Ť":"T","Ţ":"T","Ṱ":"T","Ț":"T","Ⱦ":"T","Ṫ":"T","Ṭ":"T","Ƭ":"T","Ṯ":"T","Ʈ":"T","Ŧ":"T","Ɐ":"A","Ꞁ":"L","Ɯ":"M","Ʌ":"V","Ꜩ":"TZ","Ú":"U","Ŭ":"U","Ǔ":"U","Û":"U","Ṷ":"U","Ü":"U","Ǘ":"U","Ǚ":"U","Ǜ":"U","Ǖ":"U","Ṳ":"U","Ụ":"U","Ű":"U","Ȕ":"U","Ù":"U","Ủ":"U","Ư":"U","Ứ":"U","Ự":"U","Ừ":"U","Ử":"U","Ữ":"U","Ȗ":"U","Ū":"U","Ṻ":"U","Ų":"U","Ů":"U","Ũ":"U","Ṹ":"U","Ṵ":"U","Ꝟ":"V","Ṿ":"V","Ʋ":"V","Ṽ":"V","Ꝡ":"VY","Ẃ":"W","Ŵ":"W","Ẅ":"W","Ẇ":"W","Ẉ":"W","Ẁ":"W","Ⱳ":"W","Ẍ":"X","Ẋ":"X","Ý":"Y","Ŷ":"Y","Ÿ":"Y","Ẏ":"Y","Ỵ":"Y","Ỳ":"Y","Ƴ":"Y","Ỷ":"Y","Ỿ":"Y","Ȳ":"Y","Ɏ":"Y","Ỹ":"Y","Ź":"Z","Ž":"Z","Ẑ":"Z","Ⱬ":"Z","Ż":"Z","Ẓ":"Z","Ȥ":"Z","Ẕ":"Z","Ƶ":"Z","Ĳ":"IJ","Œ":"OE","ᴀ":"A","ᴁ":"AE","ʙ":"B","ᴃ":"B","ᴄ":"C","ᴅ":"D","ᴇ":"E","ꜰ":"F","ɢ":"G","ʛ":"G","ʜ":"H","ɪ":"I","ʁ":"R","ᴊ":"J","ᴋ":"K","ʟ":"L","ᴌ":"L","ᴍ":"M","ɴ":"N","ᴏ":"O","ɶ":"OE","ᴐ":"O","ᴕ":"OU","ᴘ":"P","ʀ":"R","ᴎ":"N","ᴙ":"R","ꜱ":"S","ᴛ":"T","ⱻ":"E","ᴚ":"R","ᴜ":"U","ᴠ":"V","ᴡ":"W","ʏ":"Y","ᴢ":"Z","á":"a","ă":"a","ắ":"a","ặ":"a","ằ":"a","ẳ":"a","ẵ":"a","ǎ":"a","â":"a","ấ":"a","ậ":"a","ầ":"a","ẩ":"a","ẫ":"a","ä":"a","ǟ":"a","ȧ":"a","ǡ":"a","ạ":"a","ȁ":"a","à":"a","ả":"a","ȃ":"a","ā":"a","ą":"a","ᶏ":"a","ẚ":"a","å":"a","ǻ":"a","ḁ":"a","ⱥ":"a","ã":"a","ꜳ":"aa","æ":"ae","ǽ":"ae","ǣ":"ae","ꜵ":"ao","ꜷ":"au","ꜹ":"av","ꜻ":"av","ꜽ":"ay","ḃ":"b","ḅ":"b","ɓ":"b","ḇ":"b","ᵬ":"b","ᶀ":"b","ƀ":"b","ƃ":"b","ɵ":"o","ć":"c","č":"c","ç":"c","ḉ":"c","ĉ":"c","ɕ":"c","ċ":"c","ƈ":"c","ȼ":"c","ď":"d","ḑ":"d","ḓ":"d","ȡ":"d","ḋ":"d","ḍ":"d","ɗ":"d","ᶑ":"d","ḏ":"d","ᵭ":"d","ᶁ":"d","đ":"d","ɖ":"d","ƌ":"d","ı":"i","ȷ":"j","ɟ":"j","ʄ":"j","ǳ":"dz","ǆ":"dz","é":"e","ĕ":"e","ě":"e","ȩ":"e","ḝ":"e","ê":"e","ế":"e","ệ":"e","ề":"e","ể":"e","ễ":"e","ḙ":"e","ë":"e","ė":"e","ẹ":"e","ȅ":"e","è":"e","ẻ":"e","ȇ":"e","ē":"e","ḗ":"e","ḕ":"e","ⱸ":"e","ę":"e","ᶒ":"e","ɇ":"e","ẽ":"e","ḛ":"e","ꝫ":"et","ḟ":"f","ƒ":"f","ᵮ":"f","ᶂ":"f","ǵ":"g","ğ":"g","ǧ":"g","ģ":"g","ĝ":"g","ġ":"g","ɠ":"g","ḡ":"g","ᶃ":"g","ǥ":"g","ḫ":"h","ȟ":"h","ḩ":"h","ĥ":"h","ⱨ":"h","ḧ":"h","ḣ":"h","ḥ":"h","ɦ":"h","ẖ":"h","ħ":"h","ƕ":"hv","í":"i","ĭ":"i","ǐ":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ḯ":"i","ị":"i","ȉ":"i","ì":"i","ỉ":"i","ȋ":"i","ī":"i","į":"i","ᶖ":"i","ɨ":"i","ĩ":"i","ḭ":"i","ꝺ":"d","ꝼ":"f","ᵹ":"g","ꞃ":"r","ꞅ":"s","ꞇ":"t","ꝭ":"is","ǰ":"j","ĵ":"j","ʝ":"j","ɉ":"j","ḱ":"k","ǩ":"k","ķ":"k","ⱪ":"k","ꝃ":"k","ḳ":"k","ƙ":"k","ḵ":"k","ᶄ":"k","ꝁ":"k","ꝅ":"k","ĺ":"l","ƚ":"l","ɬ":"l","ľ":"l","ļ":"l","ḽ":"l","ȴ":"l","ḷ":"l","ḹ":"l","ⱡ":"l","ꝉ":"l","ḻ":"l","ŀ":"l","ɫ":"l","ᶅ":"l","ɭ":"l","ł":"l","ǉ":"lj","ſ":"s","ẜ":"s","ẛ":"s","ẝ":"s","ḿ":"m","ṁ":"m","ṃ":"m","ɱ":"m","ᵯ":"m","ᶆ":"m","ń":"n","ň":"n","ņ":"n","ṋ":"n","ȵ":"n","ṅ":"n","ṇ":"n","ǹ":"n","ɲ":"n","ṉ":"n","ƞ":"n","ᵰ":"n","ᶇ":"n","ɳ":"n","ñ":"n","ǌ":"nj","ó":"o","ŏ":"o","ǒ":"o","ô":"o","ố":"o","ộ":"o","ồ":"o","ổ":"o","ỗ":"o","ö":"o","ȫ":"o","ȯ":"o","ȱ":"o","ọ":"o","ő":"o","ȍ":"o","ò":"o","ỏ":"o","ơ":"o","ớ":"o","ợ":"o","ờ":"o","ở":"o","ỡ":"o","ȏ":"o","ꝋ":"o","ꝍ":"o","ⱺ":"o","ō":"o","ṓ":"o","ṑ":"o","ǫ":"o","ǭ":"o","ø":"o","ǿ":"o","õ":"o","ṍ":"o","ṏ":"o","ȭ":"o","ƣ":"oi","ꝏ":"oo","ɛ":"e","ᶓ":"e","ɔ":"o","ᶗ":"o","ȣ":"ou","ṕ":"p","ṗ":"p","ꝓ":"p","ƥ":"p","ᵱ":"p","ᶈ":"p","ꝕ":"p","ᵽ":"p","ꝑ":"p","ꝙ":"q","ʠ":"q","ɋ":"q","ꝗ":"q","ŕ":"r","ř":"r","ŗ":"r","ṙ":"r","ṛ":"r","ṝ":"r","ȑ":"r","ɾ":"r","ᵳ":"r","ȓ":"r","ṟ":"r","ɼ":"r","ᵲ":"r","ᶉ":"r","ɍ":"r","ɽ":"r","ↄ":"c","ꜿ":"c","ɘ":"e","ɿ":"r","ś":"s","ṥ":"s","š":"s","ṧ":"s","ş":"s","ŝ":"s","ș":"s","ṡ":"s","ṣ":"s","ṩ":"s","ʂ":"s","ᵴ":"s","ᶊ":"s","ȿ":"s","ɡ":"g","ᴑ":"o","ᴓ":"o","ᴝ":"u","ť":"t","ţ":"t","ṱ":"t","ț":"t","ȶ":"t","ẗ":"t","ⱦ":"t","ṫ":"t","ṭ":"t","ƭ":"t","ṯ":"t","ᵵ":"t","ƫ":"t","ʈ":"t","ŧ":"t","ᵺ":"th","ɐ":"a","ᴂ":"ae","ǝ":"e","ᵷ":"g","ɥ":"h","ʮ":"h","ʯ":"h","ᴉ":"i","ʞ":"k","ꞁ":"l","ɯ":"m","ɰ":"m","ᴔ":"oe","ɹ":"r","ɻ":"r","ɺ":"r","ⱹ":"r","ʇ":"t","ʌ":"v","ʍ":"w","ʎ":"y","ꜩ":"tz","ú":"u","ŭ":"u","ǔ":"u","û":"u","ṷ":"u","ü":"u","ǘ":"u","ǚ":"u","ǜ":"u","ǖ":"u","ṳ":"u","ụ":"u","ű":"u","ȕ":"u","ù":"u","ủ":"u","ư":"u","ứ":"u","ự":"u","ừ":"u","ử":"u","ữ":"u","ȗ":"u","ū":"u","ṻ":"u","ų":"u","ᶙ":"u","ů":"u","ũ":"u","ṹ":"u","ṵ":"u","ᵫ":"ue","ꝸ":"um","ⱴ":"v","ꝟ":"v","ṿ":"v","ʋ":"v","ᶌ":"v","ⱱ":"v","ṽ":"v","ꝡ":"vy","ẃ":"w","ŵ":"w","ẅ":"w","ẇ":"w","ẉ":"w","ẁ":"w","ⱳ":"w","ẘ":"w","ẍ":"x","ẋ":"x","ᶍ":"x","ý":"y","ŷ":"y","ÿ":"y","ẏ":"y","ỵ":"y","ỳ":"y","ƴ":"y","ỷ":"y","ỿ":"y","ȳ":"y","ẙ":"y","ɏ":"y","ỹ":"y","ź":"z","ž":"z","ẑ":"z","ʑ":"z","ⱬ":"z","ż":"z","ẓ":"z","ȥ":"z","ẕ":"z","ᵶ":"z","ᶎ":"z","ʐ":"z","ƶ":"z","ɀ":"z","ﬀ":"ff","ﬃ":"ffi","ﬄ":"ffl","ﬁ":"fi","ﬂ":"fl","ĳ":"ij","œ":"oe","ﬆ":"st","ₐ":"a","ₑ":"e","ᵢ":"i","ⱼ":"j","ₒ":"o","ᵣ":"r","ᵤ":"u","ᵥ":"v","ₓ":"x","ί":"ι"};

String.prototype.latinise = function(){
    return this.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\[\] ]/g, function(a){
        return Latinise.latin_map[a]||a
    })
};
String.prototype.latinize=String.prototype.latinise;
                                                                     
function enumerarLetras(texto){
   var str = texto.latinize().replace(/\s+/g, '');
   var numeros = [];
   str.split('').map(function(letra){
      var numero = letra.charCodeAt();
      switch(true){
         case (numero >= 97 && numero <= 122):    // Latin - letras minúsculas
            numero -= 96;
            break;
         case (numero >= 65 && numero <= 90):     // Latin - letras MAIÚSCULAS
            numero -= 64;
            break;
         case (numero >= 1072 && numero <= 1103): // Russo - letras minúsculas
            numero -= 1071;
            break;
         case (numero >= 1040 && numero <= 1071): // Russo - letras MAIÚSCULAS
            numero -= 1039;
            break;
         case (numero >= 945 && numero <= 969):   // Grego - letras minúsculas
            numero -= 944;
            break;
         case (numero >= 913 && numero <= 937):   // Grego - letras MAIÚSCULAS
            numero -= 912;
            break;                                    
      }                                                                                                                                           
      numeros.push(numero);
    });
    return numeros;
}

alert(enumerarLetras("stack Overflow"));
alert(enumerarLetras("переполнение стека"));
alert(enumerarLetras("Υπερχείλιση στοίβας"));
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma alternativa é analizar o charCode de cada caracter.

```js
var getNumeros = function (palavra) {
    var numeros = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < palavra.length; ++i)
    {
        //Latin - minusculo
        var numero = palavra.charCodeAt(i);
        if (numero >= 65 && numero <= 90)
            numero -= 64;
        
        //Latin - maisculo
        if (numero >= 97 && numero <= 122)
            numero -= 96;
            
        //Russo - minusculo
        if (numero >= 1040 && numero <= 1071)
            numero -= 1039;
        
        //Russo - maisculo
        if (numero >= 1072 && numero <= 1103)
            numero -= 1071;
            
        numeros.push(numero);
    }
    return numeros;
}

var content = document.getElementById("content");
var createDiv = function(palavra) {    
    var div = document.createElement('h1');
    div.innerHTML = palavra + ' => ' + getNumeros(palavra);
    content.appendChild(div);
}

createDiv('abyz');
createDiv('ABYZ');
createDiv('абюя');
createDiv('АБЮЯ');
```

```html
<div id="content">
    
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, estou verificando por letras minusculas e maiúsculas, tanto do Latin e Russo.
O codigo acima não vai funcionar para com palavras que tenham acentos/diacríticos, neste caso será necessário remover todos.

caso precise faze-lo, pode olhar o seguinte topico no [SOen - Javascript, Remove-Accents/Diacritics in Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-diacritics-in-strings):

Comment: Os seus comentários no código estão invertidos. =)

Answer (score 5):

Aqui vai uma forma que sabe tratar acentos e trabalha com os alfabetos latino, cirílico e grego:

```js
var latinoMaiusculo = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var latinoMinusculo = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var cirilicoMaiusculo = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
var cirilicoMinusculo = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
var gregoMaiusculo = "ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ";
var gregoMinusculo = "αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω";

function eliminarAcento(letra) {
  var acentos = [
    {de: "áåãàâä", para: "a"},
    {de: "ÁÅÃÀÂÄ", para: "A"},
    {de: "éêèë", para: "e"},
    {de: "ÉÊÈË", para: "E"},
    {de: "íîìï", para: "i"},
    {de: "ÍÎÌÏ", para: "I"},
    {de: "óõòôö", para: "o"},
    {de: "ÓÕÒÔÖ", para: "O"},
    {de: "úùûü", para: "u"},
    {de: "ÚÙÛÜ", para: "U"},
    {de: "ý", para: "y"},
    {de: "Ý", para: "Y"},
    {de: "ç", para: "c"},
    {de: "Ç", para: "C"},
    {de: "ñ", para: "n"},
    {de: "Ñ", para: "N"},
    {de: "ά", para: "α"},
    {de: "έ", para: "ε"},
    {de: "ή", para: "η"},
    {de: "ίϊ", para: "ι"},
    {de: "ό", para: "ο"},
    {de: "ύϋ", para: "υ"},
    {de: "ώ", para: "ω"},
    {de: "Ά", para: "Α"},
    {de: "Έ", para: "Ε"},
    {de: "Ή", para: "Η"},
    {de: "ΊΪ", para: "Ι"},
    {de: "Ό", para: "Ο"},
    {de: "ΎΫ", para: "Υ"},
    {de: "Ώ", para: "Ω"},
    {de: "ς", para: "σ"}
  ];
  for (e in acentos) {
    for (var a = 0; a < acentos[e].de.length; a++) {
      if (letra === acentos[e].de[a]) return acentos[e].para;
    }
  }
  return letra;
}

function enumerar(texto) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < texto.length; i++) {
    var letra = eliminarAcento(texto[i]);
    var pos = latinoMaiusculo.indexOf(letra);
    if (pos === -1) pos = latinoMinusculo.indexOf(letra);
    if (pos === -1) pos = cirilicoMaiusculo.indexOf(letra);
    if (pos === -1) pos = cirilicoMinusculo.indexOf(letra);
    if (pos === -1) pos = gregoMaiusculo.indexOf(letra);
    if (pos === -1) pos = gregoMinusculo.indexOf(letra);
    array.push(pos + 1);
  }
  return array;
}

alert(enumerar("Conceição Хорошо Ελληνικό"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode se aproveitar do fato que, no Unicode, as letras costumam já vir codificadas na mesma sequência que elas aparecem nos alfabetos do dia a dia. Isso não é garantido, entretanto, por isso sugiro conferir as tabelas Unicode relevantes e - se observar alguma discrepância entre o que você quer e o que o Unicode disponibiliza (difícil, mas possível) - então especificar um alfabeto você mesmo (tal como [sugerido por Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54417/215)).

A título de exemplo, em [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (subconjunto do Unicode) a letra `A` (maiúscula) possui o *code point* `65` (`0x41` em hexadecimal), o `B` `66` (`0x42`), o `C` `67` (`0x43`) e assim por diante. De modo que basta você obter o código da letra - usando [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) (no EcmaScript 6 também existirá o [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt), mas a menos que você queira trabalhar com caracteres mais incomuns - como Chinês tradicional - você não precisa dele) - e subtrair `0x40` (1 a menos que a letra `A`) para transformar cada letra no código desejado:

```js
var str = "ABRACADABRA";
for ( var i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++ ) {
  var cod = str.charCodeAt(i) - 0x40;
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += "<p>" + cod + "</p>";
}
```

Para o alfabeto [Cirílico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode) (usado no idioma Russo), a letra base é `А`, *code point* `0x0410`. `Б` é `0x0411`, `В` é `0x0412` e assim por diante:

```js
var str = "АБГ";
for ( var i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++ ) {
  var cod = str.charCodeAt(i) - 0x040f;
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += "<p>" + cod + "</p>";
}
```

**Nota:** o código da minha resposta faz distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas; se você não quer essa distinção, transforme a *string* inteira em maiúsculas (através de [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)) antes de usá-lo. Caso contrário, para referência o `a` minúsculo possui código `97` (`0x61`) e o `а` cirílico possui código `0x0430`.

Answer (score 0):

precisei disso para um trabalho
e fiz de uma maneira bem simples
deixo aqui para quem precisar de ajuda.

```
 <script>
    var x = prompt("digite uma letra");

    if (isNaN(x) == false) {

        alert("nao é uma letra");
    } else {

        var alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";



        //  transforma em maiusculo e joga em outra variavel, pois a variavel original nao é alterada
        var y = x.toUpperCase();
        // pega a posição da letra no alfabeto, a posição começa em 0 por isso transformo em int para somar +1

        var conta = parseInt(alfabeto.indexOf(y));
        alert(conta + 1);


    }
</script>
```