# Tranformar letras em números com uma function

Tags: php, javascript, input

Estou desenvolvendo um código que consiste em pegar uma letra e tranformá-la em um número correspondente (Exemplo A->1, B->2...), e essa letra é recebida através de um `input text`.

Encontrei um tópico que me ajudou na parte de conversão desses valores aqui: [Função que enumera letras do alfabeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54414/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-enumera-letras-do-alfabeto)

porém, preciso saber como executar esse calculo com as letras que o usuário digitar

Por enquanto meu código está assim:

index.php

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> Leituras de Dados Excel </title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="excel.php" method="post">
            <div style="background-color:blue; height:130px; width:190px; position:absolute; top: 250px; left:600px;">
                <br>
                    <input id="1" name="coord1" type="text" class="input" style="position:relative; left:10; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center;" maxlength="1">
                    <input id="2" name="coord2" type="text" class="input" style="position:absolute; left:70; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center;"maxlength="1">
                    <input id="3" name="coord3" type="text" class="input" style="position:absolute; left:130; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:30px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align:center;"maxlength="1">
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Converter" style="position:relative; left:55;">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

excel.php

```
<?php
    $coord1 = $_REQUEST['coord1'];
    $coord2 = $_REQUEST['coord2'];
    $coord3 = $_REQUEST['coord3'];

    $coordenadaFinal = $coord1."-".$coord2."-".$coord3;    
?>

<html>
<head><tile>Resultado</tile>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function primeira(){
            function converte(letras) {
                var alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                var codigos = [];
                for (var i in letras) {
                    codigos.push(alfabeto.indexOf(letras[i].toUpperCase()) + 1);
                }
                return codigos;
            }

            resultado = converte("l");
                for (var i in resultado) {
                    alert(resultado);

                }
        } // fim da function geral 

        function segunda(){
                    function converte(letras) {
                        var alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                        var codigos = [];
                        for (var i in letras) {
                            codigos.push(alfabeto.indexOf(letras[i].toUpperCase()) + 27);
                        }
                        return codigos;
                    }

                    resultado = converte("l");
                        for (var i in resultado) {
                            alert(resultado);

                        }
                } // fim da function geral 

        function terceira(){
                    function converte(letras) {
                        var alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                        var codigos = [];
                        for (var i in letras) {
                            codigos.push(alfabeto.indexOf(letras[i].toUpperCase()) + 703);
                        }
                        return codigos;
                    }

                    resultado = converte("o");
                        for (var i in resultado) {
                            alert(resultado);

                        }
                } // fim da function geral 

    </script>   
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="resposta" style="background-color:blue; height:130px; width:190px; position:absolute; top: 250px; left:600px; font-size:30px; color:white;"> 
            <p>Você inseriu:</p>
            <p><?php echo strtoupper($coordenadaFinal) ; ?></p>
            <input type="button" value="Voltar" onclick="javascript: location.href='index.php';" >
            <input type="button" value="Mostrar valor 1" onclick="primeira()" >
            <input type="button" value="Mostrar valor 2" onclick="segunda()" >
            <input type="button" value="Mostrar valor 3" onclick="terceira()" >

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Tudo está funcionando corretamente, ele recebe as varáveis que a princípio eu deveria tratar, e executa a `function` com os valores que eu estabeleci corretamente dentro de `resultado = converte("alguma letra");`, porém eu não estou conseguindo passar para o valor da function a letra que o usuário digitou e que está armazenada em `cood1`, `coord2` e `coord3`.

Já tentei algumas coisas como:
resultado = converte("coord1");
resultado = converte(coord1);
resultado = converte($_REQUEST['coord1']);

Mas não obtive sucesso em nenhuma delas... 
Agradeço desde já :)

Comment: Tenta assim `resultado = converte("<?php echo $coord1;?>");`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente *-* Agradeço