# Remover acentos (javascript)

Tags: javascript, acentuação

Tenho este script abaixo com a função `toLowerCase();`

Gostaria de adicionar uma outra função à função `toLowerCase();`

Como ficaria a linha com as duas funções juntas?

```
<script language="">

function kw_list ()

{

this.keywords = new Array ();

this.num_words = 0;

this.query = "";

this.original_query = "";

this.query_length = 0;

this.possible_points = 0;

this.multiple = points_title + points_keywords + points_description;

this.get_words = get_query;

this.no_query = no_query_found;

}


function get_query ()

{

this.query = top.location.search.substring (top.location.search.indexOf ('=') + 1);

while ((the_plus = (this.query.indexOf ("+", 0))) != -1)

{

this.query_length = this.query.length;

this.query = this.query.substring (0, the_plus) + " " + this.query.substring (the_plus + 1);

}

this.original_query = unescape (this.query);

this.query = this.original_query.toLowerCase ();

this.query_length = this.query.length;  

if (this.query != "")

{

var query_pointer = 0;

var end_word = 0;

var at_end = 0;

while ((this.num_words <= (max_keywords - 1)) && (! at_end))

{

end_word = this.query.indexOf (" ", query_pointer);

if (end_word == query_pointer)

query_pointer++;

else

{

if (end_word >= (this.query_length - 1))

at_end = 1;

if (end_word != -1)

this.keywords[this.num_words] = (this.query.substring (query_pointer, end_word)).toLowerCase ();

else

{

this.keywords[this.num_words] = this.query.substring (query_pointer, this.query_length);

at_end = 1;

}

this.num_words++;

if (query_pointer != -1)

query_pointer = end_word + 1;

if (query_pointer > (this.query_length - 1))

at_end = 1;

}

}

if (this.num_words == 0)

return (0);

else

{

this.possible_points = this.multiple * this.num_words;

return (1);

}

}

else

return (0);

}



function no_query_found ()

{

document.writeln ('<link rel="stylesheet" href="gp.css">');

document.writeln ('<CENTER><P>Pesquisa em branco.</P></CENTER>');

}

function entry (url, title, keywords, description)

{

this.url = url;

this.title = title;

this.keywords = keywords;

this.description = description;

this.points = 0;

this.search_entry = find_keyword;

this.print_entry = print_result;

}

function find_keyword (the_word)

{

var the_title = this.title.toLowerCase ();

var the_keywords = this.keywords.toLowerCase ();

var the_description = this.description.toLowerCase ();

if ((the_title.indexOf (the_word)) != -1)

this.points += points_title;

if ((the_keywords.indexOf (the_word)) != -1)

this.points += points_keywords;

if ((the_description.indexOf (the_word)) != -1)

this.points += points_description;

}



function print_result (possible_points)

{

document.writeln ('<CENTER><P><A HREF="' + this.url + '" target="meio">' + this.title + '</A>' + this.description + '</P></CENTER>');

}



function no_entry_printed (the_query)

{

document.writeln ('<link rel="stylesheet" href="gp.css">');

document.writeln ("<CENTER><P> Não há Ocorrências para <U><B>" + the_query + "</B></U>.</P></CENTER>"); 

}



function print_intro (the_query)

{

document.writeln ("<CENTER><P>Pesquisando por <U><B>" + the_query + "</B></U>:</P></CENTER>"); 

}

function begin_search ()

{

var key_list = new kw_list;

var entry_printed = 0;

if (! key_list.get_words ())

key_list.no_query ();

else

{

var counter = 0;

var counter2 = 0;

for (counter = 0; counter < entry_num; counter++)

for (counter2 = 0; counter2 <= (key_list.num_words - 1); counter2++)

the_entries[counter].search_entry (key_list.keywords[counter2]);

for (counter = key_list.possible_points; counter > 0; counter--)

{                                                                        

for (counter2 = 0; counter2 < entry_num; counter2++)

{

if (counter == the_entries[counter2].points)

{

if (entry_printed != 1)

{

entry_printed = 1;

print_intro (key_list.original_query);

}

the_entries[counter2].print_entry (key_list.possible_points);

}

}

}

if (! entry_printed)

no_entry_printed (key_list.original_query);

}

}

the_entries = new Array ();
```

**A outra função é esta:**

```
function retira_acentos(str) 
{

    com_acento = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐ
ÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜ
ÝŔÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿŕ";

sem_acento = "AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDN
OOOOOOUUUUYRsBaaa
aaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuybyr";
    novastr="";
    for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        troca=false;
        for (a=0; a<com_acento.length; a++) {
            if (str.substr(i,1)==com_acento.substr(a,1)) {
                novastr+=sem_acento.substr(a,1);
                troca=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (troca==false) {
            novastr+=str.substr(i,1);
        }
    }
    return novastr;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Função que enumera letras do alfabeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54414/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-enumera-letras-do-alfabeto)

Comment: Olhe nessa outra pergunta que marquei como duplicata. Embora ela esteja pedindo algo um pouco diferente, 3 das 6 respostas de lá abordam a questão de remover os acentos, inclusive a [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54426/132).

Comment: @VictorStafusa, olhei, a questão não é a função, mas apenas onde devo chamá-la, a função já tenho e funciona, só quero saber onde devo colocar no código, desculpe não entendo nada de JAVAScript, rsrs

Comment: Removi o meu voto como duplicata.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bastaria substituir isso:

```
var the_title = this.title.toLowerCase();
```

Por isso:

```
var the_title = retira_acentos(this.title.toLowerCase());
```

Ou seja, é só chamar a função `retira_acentos` dando-lhe a string da qual os acentos devem ser removidos.

Apenas noto que a convenção/padronização de nomes no javascript dita para usar *camelCase*. Ou seja, ao invés de usar `the_title`, `the_keywords`, `retira_acentos`, etc, os nomes seriam `theTitle`, `theKeywords`, `retiraAcentos`, etc.

Answer (score 74):

Conversão em uma linha simples e fácil:

```
string.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
```

Comment: Aí sim! Resolveu de forma muito prática!

Comment: Mandou muito bem! simples e funcional, perfeito!

Comment: Excelente e olha que eu nem gosto de JS kkkk

Answer (score 13):

Utilize esta função:

```
function removeAcento (text)
{       
    text = text.toLowerCase();                                                         
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÁÀÂÃ]','gi'), 'a');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÉÈÊ]','gi'), 'e');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÍÌÎ]','gi'), 'i');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÓÒÔÕ]','gi'), 'o');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[ÚÙÛ]','gi'), 'u');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('[Ç]','gi'), 'c');
    return text;                 
}
```

Comment: eu já possuo a funçaõ completa, só gostaria de saber a sintaxe de duas funções juntas, por exemplo, como adiciono uma outra função, nesta linha por exemplo:

var the_keywords = this.keywords.toLowerCase ();

onde coloco esta outra função?
Obrigado por sua resposta

Comment: Não é só chamar uma função após a outra? Ou juntá-las numa só?

Comment: Tanto faz, só não sei onde e como chamar a função removeAcento junto com toLowerCase, entende?
Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Fiz um edição na minha função, que agora faz o lowercase e remove os acentos. É só chamá-la com o conteúdo entre os parentes.

Comment: Vou testar, Obrigado

Comment: Ficaria assim? por exemplo:

this.query = this.original_query.removeAcento (text);

Comment: Não... removeAcento(string); No lugar de string, coloque o nome da sua variável ou o texto entre aspas.

Comment: var nova_variavel = removeAcento(variavel);

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente LucasWmolin, muitíssimo Obrigado!

Comment: o script de remover acento que me passou, está funcionando bem no firefox, mas em outros navegadores não funciona bem, sabe dizer porq?

Comment: A princípio, deveria funcionar normalmente em qualquer navegador. O problema ainda está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 5):

Complementando as outras respostas, também é possível usar [*Unicode Property Escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) (só não esqueça de ver [quais browsers são compatíveis](https://caniuse.com/?search=Unicode%20property%20escape)):

```js
string.normalize('NFD').replace(/\p{Mn}/gu, "");
```

Primeiro ele converte a string para NFD, que já foi bem explicado [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052), mas basicamente isso "quebra" as letras acentuadas (como "á") em dois caracteres (a letra sem acento "a" e o próprio acento separadamente).

Depois o `replace` usa a regex `\p{Mn}`, e repare que tive que usar a [*flag* `u`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052) para que funcione (pois é ela que habilita o uso de *Unicode Property Escapes*).

Basicamente, ele pega todos os caracteres que estão na [categoria "Mark, Nonspacing"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) **←** Veja neste link que esta categoria possui o intervalo entre os code points U+0300 e U+036F, que é basicamente o bloco Unicode chamado [Combining Diacritical Marks](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm) e o mesmo que foi usado em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363225/112052). Mas esta categoria possui também muitos outros caracteres (a lista completa está no [link já indicado](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm)).

Claro, se as strings tiverem apenas textos em português, usar `[\u0300-\u036f]` é mais que o suficiente para remover os acentos. Mas se quiser ser mais abrangente e incluir acentos de outros alfabetos/idiomas, pode usar `\p{Mn}`. Ou, se quiser incluir mais categorias (como a [Mark, Spacing Combining](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/list.htm) e [Mark, Enclosing](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Me/list.htm)), basta trocar para `\p{M}`, que já inclui todas (e veja os respectivos links para saber quais caracteres estão inclusos).

Por fim, outra opção é colocar apenas os acentos específicos que você quer considerar, como por exemplo `/[\u0300-\u0303\u0327]/g`, que contempla apenas os acentos agudo, circunflexo e grave, além do til e da cedilha (aí ficaria bem específico para o português).

Answer (score 3):

Use um slugify

```
export const convertToSlug = (text) => {
  const a = 'àáäâãèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñçßÿœæŕśńṕẃǵǹḿǘẍźḧ·/_,:;'
  const b = 'aaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuuncsyoarsnpwgnmuxzh------'
  const p = new RegExp(a.split('').join('|'), 'g')
  return text.toString().toLowerCase().trim()
    .replace(p, c => b.charAt(a.indexOf(c))) // Replace special chars
    .replace(/&/g, '-and-') // Replace & with 'and'
    .replace(/[\s\W-]+/g, '-') // Replace spaces, non-word characters and dashes with a single dash (-)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
String.prototype.ReplaceSpecialChars = function () {
  return this
    .replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/g,"A")
    .replace(/[aáàãâä]/g,"a")
    .replace(/[EÉÈÊË]/g,"E")
    .replace(/[eéèêë]/g,"e")
    .replace(/[IÍÌÎÏ]/g,"I")
    .replace(/[iíìîï]/g,"i")
    .replace(/[OÓÒÕÔÖ]/g,"O")
    .replace(/[oóòõôö]/g,"o")
    .replace(/[UÚÙÛÜ]/g,"U")
    .replace(/[uúùûü]/g,"u")
    .replace(/[ç]/g,"c")
    .replace(/[Ç]/g,"C");
}
```

1. "Instrução".ReplaceSpecialChars();
2. "INSTRUÇÃO".ReplaceSpecialChars();