# Javascript: remover acentos e espaços

Tags: javascript, acentuação, replace

Boa tarde!

Alguém possa me ajudar a resolver o problema de como remover acentuação e espaços.

Ao selecionar estado Alagoas e cidade Barra de São Miguel, retorna assim Barra de São Miguel.html e que deveria ser substituído por barradesaomiguel.html.

Segue abaixo:

Selecione estado
            Acre
            Alagoas

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cidades = [];
   cidades.Acre = ['Rio Branco','Acrelândia','Assis Brasil','Brasiléia','Bujari','Capixaba','Cruzeiro do Sul','Epitaciolândia','Feijó','Jordão','Mâncio Lima','Manoel Urbano','Marechal Thaumaturgo','Plácido de Castro','Porto Acre','Porto Walter','Rodrigues Alves',  'Santa Rosa do Purus','Sena Madureira','Senador Guiomard','Tarauacá','Xapuri'];
   cidades.Alagoas = ['Maceió','Água Branca','Anadia','Arapiraca','Atalaia','Barra de Santo Antônio','Barra de São Miguel','Batalha','Belém','Belo Monte','Boca da Mata','Branquinha','Cacimbinhas','Cajueiro','Campestre','Campo Alegre','Campo Grande','Canapi','Capela','Carneiros','Chã Preta','Coité do Nóia','Colônia Leopoldina','Coqueiro Seco','Coruripe','Craíbas',  'Delmiro Gouveia','Dois Riachos','Estrela de Alagoas','Feira Grande','Feliz Deserto','Flexeiras','Girau do Ponciano','Ibateguara','Igaci','Igreja Nova','Inhapi','Jacaré dos Homens','Jacuípe','Japaratinga','Jaramataia','Jequiá da Praia','Joaquim Gomes','Jundiá','Junqueiro','Lagoa da Canoa','Limoeiro de Anadia','Major Isidoro','Mar Vermelho','Maragogi','Maravilha','Marechal Deodoro','Maribondo','Mata Grande','Matriz de Camaragibe','Messias','Minador do Negrão','Monteirópolis','Murici','Novo Lino','Olho d\'Água das Flores','Olho d\'Água do Casado','Olho d\'Água Grande','Olivença','Ouro Branco','Palestina','Palmeira dos Índios','Pão de Açúcar','Pariconha','Paripueira','Passo de Camaragibe','Paulo Jacinto', 'Penedo','Piaçabuçu','Pilar','Pindoba','Piranhas','Poço das Trincheiras','Porto Calvo','Porto de Pedras','Porto Real do Colégio','Quebrangulo','Rio Largo','Roteiro','Santa Luzia do Norte','Santana do Ipanema','Santana do Mundaú','São Brás','São José da Laje','São José da Tapera','São Luís do Quitunde','São Miguel dos Campos','São Miguel dos Milagres','São Sebastião','Satuba','Senador Rui Palmeira','Tanque d\'Arca','Taquarana','Teotônio Vilela','Traipu','União dos Palmares','Viçosa'];
    // ---
    function updateModels(theForm) 
     { if(theForm.estados.selectedIndex<1){return false; }
       var op=theForm.estados.options;
       var newModels = cidades[op[op.selectedIndex].value];
       theForm.cidades.options.length = 0;
       theForm.cidades.options[0] = new Option("Selecione cidade", "");
       theForm.cidades.options[0].selected = true;
       for (var i=0; i<newModels.length; i++) 
       { theForm.cidades.options[i+1] = new Option(newModels, newModels); }  
     }
    // ---
    // check both selections have been made
     document.getElementById("B1").onclick=function(event)
      { event=event || window.event;
        var targElem = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var thisForm=targElem.parentNode;
        if(thisForm.estados.selectedIndex>0 && thisForm.cidades.selectedIndex>0)
          { var cidadesP= thisForm.cidades;
                  location.href= cidadesP[cidadesP.selectedIndex].value+".html"; }
            else { return false; } 
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: coloque o código completo incluindo o HTML do formulario

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um exemplo de função que faz isso:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  function remover_acentos_espaco(str) {
  str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // remover espaco do comeco e do fim
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  
  // remover acentuacao
  var from = "ãàáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
  var to   = "aaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";
  for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
  }

  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '') // remover caracteres inválidos
    .replace(/\s+/g, '') // Remover espaços
    .replace(/-+/g, ''); //Remover traços
  return str;
}

console.log(remover_acentos_espaco("Barra de São Miguel"));
</script>
```

No console do seu navegador deve aparecer o texto sem espaços ou acentos

Comment: Já tentei isso e não funciona. São várias cidades com acentos e espaços.

Comment: @ricardosac Fiz um teste rápido aqui e aparentemente o código acima funciona (não testei para todos os casos, então posso estar enganado). Mas se não é isso que vc precisa, basta editar sua pergunta colocando mais alguns exemplos e dando mais detalhes sobre o que exatamente não funcionou (quais casos falha, por exemplo). Complementando, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237762/112052) tem algumas opções de código para retirar os acentos, e basta juntar com o trecho acima que remove os espaços e acredito que estará resolvido...

Comment: Se vc já faz o replace que remove os espaços, não precisa do primeiro que só remove do início e fim. Na verdade, acho que não precisa fazer tantas regex. Assumindo que o problema é apenas remover tudo que não é letra e eliminar os acentos, daria para fazer somente `str.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')`

Answer (score 0):

Você está colocando o nome e o valor do select como o mesmo em `new Option(newModels, newModels)`

**Você pode fazer o regex no valor, assim:**

```
new Option(newModels, newModels.normalize('NFD').replace(/[^a-z]/g, ''));
```

**Ou você pode fazer o regex na hora de pegar o valor:**

Altere a linha `location.href= cidadesP[cidadesP.selectedIndex].value+".html"; }` 
Para

```
location.href= cidadesP[cidadesP.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')+".html"; }
```