# O que é a flag Unicode "u" em expressões regulares? Qual a sua função?

Tags: javascript, regex

Há algum tempo descobri que expressões regulares também podem usar a *flag* `u`, que penso ser abreviação para *Unicode*.

- Qual o propósito dessa *flag*?
- Sei que foi adicionada em alguma versão recente do ECMAScript, então quais comportamentos ela modifica nas expressões regulares?
- Tem relação com alguma outra *flag*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta *flag* muda alguns aspectos na forma como a regex trata a string.

---

## Interpretação de code points em *Surrogate pairs*

Por exemplo, se a string tiver o emoji  (PILE OF POO). Ele é um "caractere" (no sentido de ter um code point definido pelo Unicode - [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) para mais detalhes). No caso, [o code point dele é U+1F4A9](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm), e [como já vimos aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443744/112052), code points acima de U+FFFF são armazenados internamente na forma de [*surrogate pairs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) (no caso, o emoji é "quebrado"/decomposto em dois valores: 0xD83D e 0xDCA9).

Então imagine uma regex que verifica se a string tem apenas um caractere: `/^.$/`. Esta regex tem o início e fim da string (os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`) e entre eles tem o ponto, que corresponde a um code point ([exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)).

Sem a *flag* `u`, o ponto considera que cada parte do *surrogate pair* é um code point separado. Com a *flag*, ele interpreta as duas partes do *surrogate pair* como um único code point:

```js
const s = '';
console.log(s.length); // 2 <- o codepoint usa 2 code units
console.log(s.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)); // d83d
console.log(s.charCodeAt(1).toString(16)); // dca9

// testando se tem apenas um code point
console.log(/^.$/.test(s)); // false
console.log(/^.$/u.test(s)); // true

// testando se tem dois code points
console.log(/^.{2}$/.test(s)); // true
console.log(/^.{2}$/u.test(s)); // false
```

Repare que sem a *flag*, a regex com um único ponto falha, porque ela considera que cada parte do *surrogate pair* é um code point separado (e só funciona quando usamos uma regex que busca por dois code points).

Já com a *flag*, o ponto interpreta o *surrogate pair* como um único code point, encontrando um *match* (e falhando quando procuramos por dois code points).

---

Podemos ver este comportamento também se estivermos buscando especificamente por partes do *surrogate pair*:

```js
const s = '';

// buscando pelas partes do surrogate pair
console.log(/\uD83D/.test(s)); // true
console.log(/\uDCA9/.test(s)); // true

// com a flag u, não funciona mais (pois as partes do surrogate pair não são mais verificadas separadamente)
console.log(/\uD83D/u.test(s)); // false
console.log(/\uDCA9/u.test(s)); // false
```

Ou, se eu quiser verificar se a string tem dois :

```js
const s = '';

// sem a flag, cada parte do surrogate pair é tratado separadamente
console.log(/\uD83D\uDCA9{2}/.test(s)); // false
// ou seja, o {2} é aplicado somente ao \uDCA9
console.log(/\uD83D\uDCA9{2}/.test("\uD83D\uDCA9\uDCA9")); // true

// com a flag, o {2} é aplicado a todo o surrogate pair
console.log(/\uD83D\uDCA9{2}/u.test(s)); // true
console.log(/\uD83D\uDCA9{2}/u.test("\uD83D\uDCA9\uDCA9")); // false
```

No caso, sem a *flag*, o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{2}` é aplicado somente ao `\uDCA9` (já que cada parte do *surrogate pair* é tratada separadamente), enquanto que com a *flag*, o `{2}` é aplicado a todo o *surrogate pair*, detectando corretamente que há dois emojis na string.

Isso interfere também no tamanho do *match* retornado:

```js
const s = '';

// retorna um array com 2 elementos (as partes do surrogate pair)
console.log(s.match(/./g).map(s => s.codePointAt(0).toString(16))); // ["d83d", "dca9"]

// retorna um array com 1 elemento (o próprio emoji)
console.log(s.match(/./gu).map(s => s.codePointAt(0).toString(16))); // ["1f4a9"]
```

Claro que se a string só tiver caracteres cujos code points sejam menores que U+FFFF, isso não será uma preocupação.

---

## Unicode Property Escapes

A *flag* `u` também habilita o uso de [*Unicode Property Escapes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
const s = "平仮名";

console.log(s.match(/\p{L}/gu) ); // 平 仮 名
console.log(s.match(/\p{L}/g) ); // null
```

No caso, `\p{L}` procura por qualquer code point que seja uma letra definida pelo Unicode (são todas as categorias que começam com "L" [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)). Mas isso só funciona se tiver a *flag* `u` habilitada.

Não vou citar todas as possibilidades de Unicode Properties, mas pela [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) já dá para ter uma boa ideia das opções existentes.
Mas apenas para citar um exemplo, um uso seria para contornar a limitação de [atalhos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) como `\w` e `\b`, que em JavaScript só consideram os caracteres ASCII (mesmo com a *flag* `u` habilitada). Exemplo:

```js
// \b e \w não levam em conta caracteres acentuados
console.log('sábia sabiá'.match(/\b\w+\b/gu)); // ["s", "bia", "sabi"]

// \p{L} leva em conta caracteres acentuados
console.log('sábia sabiá'.match(/(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?!\p{L})/gu)); // ["sábia", "sabiá"]
```

---

## Escapes e atributo `pattern`

Existe ainda outro detalhe (que já foi descrito [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/477556/112052)): quando a *flag* `u` está presente, somentes alguns caracteres podem ser escapados com `\` - no caso, são apenas: `^` `$` `\` `.` `*` `+` `?` `(` `)` `[` `]` `{` `}` `|`.

Ou seja, uma regex que tenha algo como `\-` funciona normalmente sem a *flag* (é interpretado como um hífen mesmo), mas com a *flag* dá erro:

```js
// sem a flag u - funciona
let semUnicode = /\d\-\d/;
console.log('válido:', semUnicode);

// com a flag u - erro
let comUnicode = /\d\-\d/u;
console.log('Não vai imprimir esta mensagem porque dá erro na linha acima');
```

Isso porque `\-` é redundante, já que basta colocar `-` para que seja interpretado como um hífen (exceto dentro de uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), na qual o hífen tem significado especial: `[a-z]` é uma letra de `a` a `z` e `[a\-z]` é "a letra `a`, ou um hífen, ou a letra `z`").

Outro ponto é que no [atributo `pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) de um campo HTML, a regex **sempre** é compilada com a *flag* `u` habilitada.

---

## *Unicode code point escapes*

Outro recurso que é habilitado com a *flag* `u` é o uso de *code point escape* para valores acima de U+FFFF:

```js
const s = '';

// sem a flag, procura literalmente por "u{1f4a9}"
let r = /\u{1f4a9}/;
console.log(r.test(s)); // false
console.log(r.test('u{1f4a9}')); // true

// com a flag, procura pelo code point U+1F4A9
r = /\u{1f4a9}/u;
console.log(r.test(s)); // true
console.log(r.test('u{1f4a9}')); // false
```

Para valores abaixo de U+FFFF, como já vimos nos exemplos acima, basta usar `\uHHHH` (onde `HHHH` é o valor do code point em hexadecimal), e nem precisa da *flag* para tal (ela só muda a intepretação dos *surrogate pairs*). Mas para valores acima de U+FFFF precisamos usar a sintaxe `\u{...}` (o valor do code point fica entre chaves), e para que isso funcione, precisa da *flag* `u` habilitada (caso contrário, ele buscará literalmente pelos caracteres `u`, `{`, etc).

---

## Quantificadores

Outro caso que dá diferença (conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/531438/112052)):

```js
// sem flag "u", OK
let r1 = /[a-z]{,2}/;
console.log('regex ok', r1);

// com flag "u", erro (Incomplete quantifier)
let r2 = /[a-z]{,2}/u;
console.log('não será impresso, pois dá erro na linha acima', r2);
```

Repare que a primeira regex não dá erro, mas a segunda sim. A presença da *flag* `u` faz com que a sintaxe se torne mais restrita e não aceite o quantificador sem o valor inicial (dá um erro: "*Incomplete quantifier*").

Para corrigir, deve-se indicar explicitamente que o valor mínimo é zero:

```js
// indicar o valor mínimo igual a zero
let r = /[a-z]{0,2}/u;
console.log('regex OK', r);
```

Vale lembrar ainda que `{,2}`, embora não dê erro sem a *flag* `u`, **não** é interpretado como um quantificador, e sim como literalmente o caractere `{`, seguido de vírgula, seguido de `2`, seguido de `}`. Veja:

```js
let r = /[a-z]{,2}/;

// no máximo 2 letras (não funciona)
console.log(r.test('a')); // false

// porque a regex na verdade é "uma letra, seguida de {,2}"
console.log(r.test('a{,2}')); // true
```

---

## Relação com outras *flags*

Não existe uma relação direta com outras *flags*, mas pode ser usada em conjunto (como em alguns exemplos acima, que têm a *flag* `g` também).

Mas claro que isso pode dar diferença em alguns casos, graças às esquisitices do Unicode. Por exemplo, se eu quiser buscar por todos os codepoints que equivalem à letra "s" de forma *case insensitive* (portanto, usando a *flag* `i`):

```js
console.log('Com a flag:');
let r = /s/iu;
for (let i = 0; i <= 0x10ffff; i++) {
    const s = String.fromCodePoint(i);
    if (r.test(s)) {
        console.log(`${i.toString(16)} = ${s}`);
    }
}

console.log('\n-----------------\nSem a flag:');
r = /s/i;
for (let i = 0; i <= 0x10ffff; i++) {
    const s = String.fromCodePoint(i);
    if (r.test(s)) {
        console.log(`${i.toString(16)} = ${s}`);
    }
}
```

Sem a *flag* `u`, somente as letras `s` e `S` são encontradas. Mas com a *flag*, também é encontrada a letra `ſ` ([LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/17f/index.htm)).

---

## Terminologia

O nome da *flag* (`u`) vem de "unicode", conforme consta na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags). E [na especificação da linguagem também há menção a este termo](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-notation):

> ***Unicode** is true if the RegExp object's [[OriginalFlags]] internal slot contains **"u"** and otherwise is false.*
> …
> *When the **Unicode flag** is true, "all characters" means the `CharSet` containing all code point values; otherwise "all characters" means the `CharSet` containing all code unit values.*

Inclusive, o segundo parágrafo acima descreve o comportamento mencionado no início, de tratar as partes de um *surrogate pair* como uma coisa só ou não.

Por fim, as instâncias de `RegExp` possuem a [propriedade `unicode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode), indicando se a *flag* está ativa ou não:

```js
let r = /abc/;
console.log(r.unicode); // false

r = /abc/u;
console.log(r.unicode); // true
```