# Regex para pegar palavra única

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Estou tentando criar uma regex que pega um valor exato dentro de um texto, exemplo:

```js
let texto = "troquei meu carro por um outro carro uma carroça"

console.log(texto.replace(/carro/g, 'barco'))
```

O problema é que a saída fica da seguinte forma:

```
troquei meu barco por um outro barco e por uma barcoça
```

Como eu poderia fazer para dar `replace` ou `match` em uma string única e literal? Pois o mesmo caso acontece caso eu digite `dez` e `dezembro` na mesma frase, e caso eu queria substitiu só o `dez` ele substitiu `dezembro` também.

Sou iniciante com regex, por isso estou com bastante dificuldade.

Agradeço desde já se puderem me ajudar.

Comment: `\bcarro\b` o character \b delimita uma palavra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você usou a [*flag* `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) (essa letra "g" depois da segunda barra), o que faz com que todas as ocorrências sejam substituídas. Então a primeira coisa é removê-la. **Mas isso não resolve todos os problemas**, por exemplo:

```js
let texto = "troquei minha carroça por um carro";
// não funciona, troca "carroça" por "barcoça"
console.log(texto.replace(/carro/, 'barco'));
```

Quando a regex não tem a *flag* `g`, o [método `String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) substitui somente a primeira ocorrência que for encontrada. No caso acima, "carroça" será substituída por "barcoça", que não parece ser o que você quer.

Se a ideia é pegar somente "carro" quando for exatamente esta palavra, e não parte de uma palavra, você até *poderia* usar o [atalho `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), que indica uma "fronteira entre palavras" (*word boundary* - [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) para mais detalhes), **só que isso não funciona sempre**:

```js
let texto = "troquei meus carros por um único carro";
// funciona, troca "carro", mas não "carros"
console.log(texto.replace(/\bcarro\b/, 'barco')); // troquei meus carros por um único barco

texto = "troquei minha carroça por um carro";
// não funciona, porque \b não reconhece o "ç"
console.log(texto.replace(/\bcarro\b/, 'barco')); // troquei minha barcoça por um carro
```

No JavaScript o `\b` não reconhece acentos e `ç`, então "carroça" continua sendo substituído por "barcoça", pois o "ç" não é reconhecido como alfanumérico.

Neste caso, uma alternativa é indicar que antes e depois da palavra não tem nenhuma letra, usando [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```js
let texto = "troquei minha carroça por um carro";
console.log(texto.replace(/(?<![a-záéíóúãõâêôûç])carro(?![a-záéíóúãõâêôûç])/i, 'barco')); // troquei minha carroça por um barco
```

Ou seja, eu uso um *lookbehind* negativo (indicado por `(?<! )`) que diz que antes da palavra "carro" não pode ter nenhuma letra (e ali você coloca todas que precisar), e o *lookahead* negativo (indicado por `(?! )`) faz o mesmo para depois da palavra.

Também usei a *flag* `i` (*case insensitive*) para considerar maiúsculas e minúsculas (assim só preciso colocar "á", "ç", etc na regex). Só que isso também irá substituir "Carro" por "barco", então veja se é isso que precisa (se não for, coloque também as letras maiúsculas na lista: "Á", "Ç", etc e retire a *flag* `i`).

---

Outra alternativa é usar [*Unicode Properties*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) (lembrando que para habilitar este recurso, [precisa ter a *flag* `u`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052)):

```js
let texto = "troquei minha carroça por um carro";
console.log(texto.replace(/(?<!\p{L})carro(?!\p{L})/u, 'barco')); // troquei minha carroça por um barco
```

No caso, `\p{L}` é qualquer letra definida pelo Unicode (incluindo acentos e "ç"), então os *lookarounds* verificam se não há uma letra antes e depois da palavra.

---

Uma opção mais simples, **caso as palavras estejam separadas apenas por espaços**, seria separá-las usando [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), substituir o que precisa e depois juntar de novo:

```js
let texto = "troquei minha carroça por um carro";
let partes = texto.split(' '); // separar por espaços
for (let i = 0; i < partes.length; i++) {
    if (partes[i] === 'carro') {
        partes[i] = 'barco';
        break; // se já encontrei, não preciso continuar procurando
    }
}

// juntar com espaços
console.log(partes.join(' ')); // troquei minha carroça por um barco
```

Mas claro que se tiver vírgulas, pontuação e outros, aí já não funciona mais, e você acabaria voltando ao mesmo problema: detectar quais caracteres são partes de uma palavra, incluindo acentos e "ç", e talvez nem valha a pena fazer a quebra, pois teria que usar alguma regex complexa que exclui as letras acentuadas, etc.

Ou, você pode escolher uma lista simplificada de separadores (por exemplo, espaço, ponto final, exclamação, interrogação e vírgula):

```js
let texto = "troquei minha carroça por um carro, uma moto e um caminhão";
let partes = texto.split(/([ ,.!?]+)/);
for (let i = 0; i < partes.length; i++) {
    if (partes[i] === 'carro') {
        partes[i] = 'barco';
        break; // se já encontrei, não preciso continuar procurando
    }
}

console.log(partes.join('')); // troquei minha carroça por um barco, uma moto e um caminhão
```

Na regex usada no `split` coloquei tudo entre parênteses, formando um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Com isso, os separadores também são colocados no array `partes`, assim eu consigo juntar tudo no final. Mas isso vale se você conhece todos os caracteres que estão entre as palavras, então tem que incluir todos eles no `split`.

Answer (score 3):

Ao usar o `/g` como flag, você esta especificando para procurar em toda a string "global" e substituir, você poderia simplesmente não colocar `g` como flag, isso força o regex a retornar apenas o primeiro resultado encontrado.

```js
let texto = "troquei meu carro por um outro carro uma carroça"
console.log(texto.replace(/carro/, 'barco'))
```

[Este](https://regex101.com/) site é muito interessante para testar regex e entender o significado de casa parte da expressão escrita.