# Como evitar repetições de valor neste código?

Tags: javascript, otimização, replace

Fiz a função abaixo que remove acentos de uma string utilizando valores de um objeto:

```js
function remAcentos(p){

   var acc = {
      //    ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓         ↓
      'á': 'a', 'â': 'a', 'à': 'a', 'ã': 'a', 'â': 'a',
      //    ↓         ↓
      'é': 'e', 'ê': 'e',
      'í': 'i',
      //    ↓         ↓         ↓
      'ó': 'o', 'õ': 'o', 'ô': 'o',
      'ú': 'u'
   }

   return p.replace(/[áàãâéêíóõôú]/g, function(m){

       return acc[m];
      
   });

}

console.log(remAcentos('brásíliaóúàô'));
```

Ela possui um `replace` com um regex que casa letras acentuadas e substitui pelo valor do item no objeto e retorna a string sem os acentos.

Funciona perfeito, mas eu sou intrigado com repetições e um pouco com a estética do código (vejam as setas indicativas no código) e acho que isso pode ser otimizado, sem repetições.

Como eu poderia evitar tais repetições? Pensei em algo do tipo:

```
var acc = {
   'áâàãâ': 'a',
   'éê': 'e',
   'í': 'i',
   'óôõ': 'o',
   'ú': 'u'
}
```

Mas se eu fizer desta forma, como eu poderia pegar o valor do item no objeto `acc` quando o `replace` casar uma letra acentuada?

Comment: Veja isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54426/132

Comment: Tenho certeza que é duplicata, mas não achei nenhuma pergunta boa para colocar como duplicata.

Comment: rsrs.. tenta achar aí broder. A resposta do Isac é boa.

Comment: Achei umas que eram mal-formuladas. Mas aí acho que não é bom marcar como duplicata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para o segundo caso como cada letra está dentro de uma `string` pode percorrer as `strings` através de [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) e ver se tem a letra com [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). Caso encontre retorna o valor associado.

Exemplo:

```js
function remAcentos(p){

   var acc = {
       'áâàãâ': 'a',
       'éê': 'e',
       'í': 'i',
       'óôõ': 'o',
       'ú': 'u'
   }

   return p.replace(/[áàãâéêíóõôú]/g, function(m){
       for (let chave of Object.keys(acc)){
           if (chave.indexOf(m) !== -1){
               return acc[chave];
           }
       }     
   });

}

console.log(remAcentos('brásíliaóúàô'));
```

Poderá colocar um `return m;` no fim da função de substituição de letra se quiser precaver-se contra o caso de não ter uma letra em `acc` para a qual está a aplicar a regex. Nesse caso ao invés de apanhar `undefined` iria ficar com a mesma letra de entrada.

Comment: +1 pela excelente resposta.

Comment: Só acho que o `return m;`não seja necessário... se fizer um teste com uma string sem acento irá retorna ela mesma.

Comment: o primeiro `return` já retorna a string recebida como ela é. O replace é apenas opcional caso haja algum match

Comment: @dvd Sim é verdade mas referia me ao match de uma coisa que ficou esquecida (lapso do programador mesmo), como por exemplo não ter o `'ú':'u'` em `acc` e continuar a ter o replace com `/[...ú]/`.

Answer (score 4):

Baseada [nesta outra resposta minha aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54426/132):

```js
function eliminarAcento(palavra) {
  var latinoMaiusculo = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var latinoMinusculo = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var cirilicoMaiusculo = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
  var cirilicoMinusculo = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
  var gregoMaiusculo = "ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ";
  var gregoMinusculo = "αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω";

  function eliminarAcentoLetra(letra) {
    var acentos = [
      {de: "áåãàâä", para: "a"},
      {de: "ÁÅÃÀÂÄ", para: "A"},
      {de: "éêèë", para: "e"},
      {de: "ÉÊÈË", para: "E"},
      {de: "íîìï", para: "i"},
      {de: "ÍÎÌÏ", para: "I"},
      {de: "óõòôö", para: "o"},
      {de: "ÓÕÒÔÖ", para: "O"},
      {de: "úùûü", para: "u"},
      {de: "ÚÙÛÜ", para: "U"},
      {de: "ý", para: "y"},
      {de: "Ý", para: "Y"},
      {de: "ç", para: "c"},
      {de: "Ç", para: "C"},
      {de: "ñ", para: "n"},
      {de: "Ñ", para: "N"},
      {de: "ά", para: "α"},
      {de: "έ", para: "ε"},
      {de: "ή", para: "η"},
      {de: "ίϊ", para: "ι"},
      {de: "ό", para: "ο"},
      {de: "ύϋ", para: "υ"},
      {de: "ώ", para: "ω"},
      {de: "Ά", para: "Α"},
      {de: "Έ", para: "Ε"},
      {de: "Ή", para: "Η"},
      {de: "ΊΪ", para: "Ι"},
      {de: "Ό", para: "Ο"},
      {de: "ΎΫ", para: "Υ"},
      {de: "Ώ", para: "Ω"},
      {de: "ς", para: "σ"}
    ];
    for (var e in acentos) {
      for (var a = 0; a < acentos[e].de.length; a++) {
        if (letra === acentos[e].de[a]) return acentos[e].para;
      }
    }
    return letra;
  }

  var s = "";
  for (var i in palavra) {
    s += eliminarAcentoLetra(palavra[i]);
  }
  return s;
}

// teste
var x = "Conceição Хорошо Ελληνικό";
alert("'" + x + "' sem acentos é '" + eliminarAcento(x) + "'");
```

Funciona para os alfabetos latino, cirílico e grego.

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer assim também:

```js
function remAcentos(p){

  var acc = {
    'áâàãâ': 'a',
    'éê': 'e',
    'í': 'i',
    'óôõ': 'o',
    'ú': 'u'
  }

  return p.replace(/[áàãâéêíóõôú]/g, letra => {
  let re;
    Object.keys(acc).forEach(item => (item.indexOf(letra) !== -1) && (re = acc[item]));
    return re;
  });

}

console.log(remAcentos('brásíliaóúàô'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Minha resposta é similar à do @Isac, só mudando a sintaxe, em vez de usar `for of`, usei `for in`. Vou deixar como referência:

```js
function remAcentos(p){

   var acc = {
      'áâàãâ': 'a',
      'éê': 'e',
      'í': 'i',
      'óôõ': 'o',
      'ú': 'u'
   }

   return p.replace(/[áàãâéêíóõôú]/g, function(m){

      for(var key in acc){
         if(~key.indexOf(m)) return acc[key];
      }
      
   });

}

console.log(remAcentos('brásíliaóúàô')); // retorna "brasiliaouao"
console.log(remAcentos('brasilia')); // retorna "brasilia"
```